# Spyder css download from computer: TypeError: cannot do positional indexing on RangeIndex with these indexers

Tags: python, pandas, read-csv

Trying to download css file from my Mac on a new install of Spyder I get this error:

TypeError: cannot do positional indexing on RangeIndex with these indexers [       mod  for         out
0   MAR    4    0.000000
1  REV    4  832.992127] of type DataFrame

I have tried several different things (changing file formats, simplifying of the file, etc.).  As you can see, the current file only has two rows and columns from the csv.  I do have a new install of Spyder on a Mac.  I am using this code:
path = '/GIT/Book4.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(path)

Different csv formats, JSON,